# Compare samples with grouped data - can t-test be used?

Tags: t-test

If I have to compare the height of two samples but the data provided are grouped, e.g.

```
Height        SampleA SampleB
[150-160) cm     10      7
[160-170) cm     12      4
[170-180) cm      7     20
```

is it valid to use the t-test or should the ranges of height be treated as categories of a nominal variable?

I know you can compute e.g. the mean using the midpoints and the frequencies but is it ok to use the midpoints to check if the distributions are normal?

Comment: There is a similar question here: [CV question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/320918/ordinal-and-nominal/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use an ordered logistic (i.e., ordinal) regression, using height as the dependent variable and what sample it came from as the independent variable.

Let height be a categorical (i.e., factor) variable, where:

- 1 = [150-160) cm
- 2 = [160-170) cm
- 3 = [170-180) cm

I assume the numbers under SampleA and SampleB are frequency counts. To create this data frame in R, you can do:

```
sample_a <- c(rep(1, 10), rep(2, 12), rep(3, 7))
sample_b <- c(rep(1, 7), rep(2, 4), rep(3, 20))
dat <- data.frame(
  height = as.factor(c(sample_a, sample_b)),
  sample = factor(c(rep("a", length(sample_a)), rep("b", length(sample_b))))
)
```

This replicates the table you provided:

```
> table(dat$height, dat$sample)

     a  b
  1 10  7
  2 12  4
  3  7 20
```

Then, you can use the `clm` function from the `ordinal` package to do the regression:

```
> library(ordinal)
> summary(clm(height ~ sample, data = dat))
formula: height ~ sample
data:    dat

 link  threshold nobs logLik AIC    niter max.grad cond.H 
 logit flexible  60   -60.78 127.56 4(0)  2.27e-10 1.1e+01

Coefficients:
        Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)  
sampleb   1.2871     0.5083   2.532   0.0113 *
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Threshold coefficients:
    Estimate Std. Error z value
1|2  -0.4104     0.3499  -1.173
2|3   0.8288     0.3649   2.271
```

Ordinary least squares regression (in this case, a t-test) cannot be used here, as you do not have a continuous dependent variable—it is an ordered category by nature. Even if the histogram *looked* normal, it still wouldn't be normally distributed, as the dependent variable is still a category.

There are many books on generalized linear models that will tell you about ordinal regression, but the best introduction I think is a chapter from *The Oxford Handbook of Quantitative Methods, Volume II: Statistical Analysis.* It is Chapter 3, "Generalized Linear Models," by Coxe, West, & Aiken.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the answer by @MarkWhite.

However, because the design in the question is simple, you could also use a test designed for a table with one categorical variable and one ordinal variable, such as the Cochran-Armitage test.

In R, this kind of test is implemented as a permutation test in the `coin` package.  Note that in this test you have to indicate the thresholds of the categories, in the `scores` option. Describing these thresholds as "symmetric" or "equidistant" is an option in the `clm` function indicated by @MarkWhite.

There's probably no advantage to using this approach rather than ordinal regression, except that it may be more convenient for data already arranged in a table.

```
### Adapted from:
###  http://rcompanion.org/handbook/H_09.html

if(!require(coin)){install.packages("coin")}

Input =(
"Sample   SampleA SampleB
Height
Low      10      7
Medium   12      4
High      7     20
")

Tabla = as.table(read.ftable(textConnection(Input)))

Tabla

sum (Tabla)

prop.table(Tabla,
           margin = 2)   ### proportion in each column
###
###  Proportion in each in column
###       Sample
### Height     SampleA   SampleB
###   Low    0.3448276 0.2258065
###   Medium 0.4137931 0.1290323
###   High   0.2413793 0.6451613

library(coin)

spineplot(t(Tabla))
```

[image: Spine plot]

```
library(coin)

Test = chisq_test(Tabla,
              scores = list("Height" = c(-1, 0, 1)))

Test

### Asymptotic Linear-by-Linear Association Test
###
### data:  Sample by Height (Low < Medium < High)
### Z = -2.4092, p-value = 0.01599
### alternative hypothesis: two.sided
```